# Failed to open Python console error message

Tags: python, error, qgis-python-console

In the past, I was able to open my Python console without any problems on QGIS. However, just recently, I tried to open the Python console on QGIS 2.18.2 (Las Palmas) on my mac, but I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 2, in 
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/console/console.py", line 46, in show_console
    _console = PythonConsole(parent)
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/console/console.py", line 83, in __init__
    self.console = PythonConsoleWidget(self)
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/console/console.py", line 109, in __init__
    self.shell = ShellScintilla(self)
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/console/console_sci.py", line 86, in __init__
    self.refreshSettingsShell()
  File "/Applications/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/python/console/console_sci.py", line 141, in refreshSettingsShell
    self.setCaretForegroundColor(cursorColor)
TypeError: QsciScintilla.setCaretForegroundColor(QColor): argument 1 has unexpected type 'unicode'
```

I have no idea what any of this means. I originally downloaded QGIS from kyngchaos.com, and redownloaded from the same source to see if it would work, but it didn't.

Comment: I had a similar problem with the python console and deleted the preference file. Indeed, one loses all GUI customisations, including de-activating all installed plugins which I was not expecting. However, this continues to happen every time I close and open QGIS, even if I don't delete the preference file anymore. Basically, after deleting it one time, QGIS continues to start from scratch every time. I use QGIS 2.18.15 on macOS Sierra.

Comment: Hello Codrina, welcome to GIS.SE. As annoying as your problem is, please consider asking a new question and refer to this question instead of posting a comment as an answer. Thank you.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/150069)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://gis.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/150069)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem here and I found a work around on this similar issue
[QGIS python error](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/220478/qgis-python-error)

you just need to remove the file containing your preferences at:

```
/Users/<your_username>/Library/Preferences/org.qgis.QGIS2.plist
```

As pointed on the answer, QGIS recreates the file on the next launch. It worked perfectly here, it's not a solution to the bug but allow you to get back the console working. The problem is you will lose all of your GUI customizations, but the rest remains unchanged.