# Failed to open Python console

Tags: pyqgis, mac

Python was working and then suddenly [image: Error message window]

I have attempted to find /Users//Library/Preferences/org.qgis.QGIS2.plist as advised in [Failed to open Python console error message](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/226380/failed-to-open-python-console-error-message) but this is not in my preferences folder. 
I am running Las Palmas 2.18.14 on Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.2.

Is there a way to troubleshoot the problem or does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Did you find anything related to QGIS in that directory?

Comment: No, QGIS or Python are not mentioned anywhere

Comment: Possible duplicated https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/266418/49538

Answer (score 1):

In my settings not all plists where displayed, cmd+shift+h then click view and show view options, then select display library, then org.qgis.QGIS2.plist became visible.

I then moved it to trash and opened QGIS again but the same problem occurred two more times.

You have to ensure that it is removed from the trash as well otherwise the same problem occurred.